# Como fazer condição em duas tabelas diferentes com sequelize?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize-js

Como posso fazer esse select no sequelize?

```
  select 
        prestadores.status, 
        financeiros.status as prestador_status from prestadores  
  left join financeiros on prestadores.financeiro_id = financeiros.financeiro_id
  where (financeiros.status = 'ok' and prestadores.status <> 'BLOQ_ADMIN' ) or 
  prestadores.status = 'LIB_ADMIN'
```

```js
  var prestadores = await Prestador.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: Financeiro,
      as: 'financeiro',
      required: false,
    }],

    where: {

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei usando o "literal" do sequelize.

```
  var prestadores = await Prestador.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: Financeiro,
      as: 'financeiro',
      required: false,
    }],

    where: literal("`Prestador`.`status` = 'LIB_ADMIN' OR `financeiro`.`status` = 'ok'"),
  });
```